# Does a square have an equation?

Tags: analytic-geometry

can you model a square in an equation ?

like a circle for example $r^2 = x^2 + y^2$

and lets say we have a square with:
centered at $(3,3)$

$2 \leq x \leq 4$ and $2 \leq y\leq 4$

can we somehow make an equation for that square ?

Comment: you can use the min() and absolute value functions

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69099/equation-of-a-rectangle

Comment: You can regard the square as the limiting set of the graphs of $$|x-3|^p + |y-3|^p=1$$ as $p\rightarrow +\infty$. Unfortunately, you can't really write $|x-3|^{\infty} + |y-3|^{\infty}=1$ without rigorously defining the symbols used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

In general,
$\left|(x - h) + (y - k)  \right|+\left| (x - h)  - (y - k)  \right|=r$ describes a square centered at (h,k) and having side length r.

Comment: The expression in the picture isn't very clear. Please format it here using [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) $\ddot\smile$

Comment: This isn't plotted in desmos is it?