# Parametric Equation for Rectangular Tubing with Corner Radius

Tags: geometry, parametrization

I'm working on a problem where I need the parametric equation for a complex shape.

[image: different shapes: circle, eclipse, rectangle, tube]

Parametric equation of a circle:

```
 x = a * cos θ
 y = a * sin θ
```

Parametric equation of an ellipse:

```
 x = a * cos θ
 y = b * sin θ
```

Parametric equation of a rectangle, [reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69099/equation-of-a-rectangle):

```
 x = a * (|cos θ| * cos θ + |sin θ| * sin θ)
 y = b * (|cos θ| * cos θ - |sin θ| * sin θ)
```

Parametric equation of a tubing with radius at the corners:

```
??  inputs = a, b and material thickness (i.e. corner radius = 2 * thickness)
```

The shape I'm trying to model is hollow rectangular steel tubing.  As manufactured, hollow steel tubing has a 'corner' radius = two times material thickness, [per standard ASTM A500-10.](http://steeltubeinstitute.org/hss/faq/corner-radii-squarerectangular-hss/)

Ultimately I'm working on a [free tube notching calculator and pattern generator](http://dogfeatherdesign.com/ttn_js/).  I'd like to add a feature for rectangular tubing to rectangular tubing.  I'm really relying on the parametric angular input to complete the model.  I'm pulling out my hair trying to develop a functional parametric equation for the hollow steel outer shape (with radius at each corner) to use in my Descriptive Geometry analysis.

Any recommendations on how to proceed here to obtain a parametrized form of a rectangle with sized corner radius?

Comment: Do you insist on a parametric form? Otherwise a piece wise defined function will do the job.

Comment: Basically, you want to corner fillet a rectangle?

Comment: @Michael, you certainly could have piecewise functions as the components of a parametric equation. I imagine B-splines and ilk would be particularly useful.

Comment: It can be a piece wise function (I'm just using JavaScript...) but I'm really relying on the angle theta, θ as the input.  I can iterate θ, perform a test, chose formula A or formula B to obtain X, Y results, iterate and repeat no problem.  But the whole thing depends on that angle as the input parameter.

Comment: @J.M.  Funny, I do have some experience with Splines, didn't even think about that approach, ref: [my website theory of CAD example.](http://dogfeatherdesign.com/software_projects/cad/2D_Curve_Overview.html)   As I look at those samples, not sure that really makes this any easier.  You know the more I think about it, why Knot.  That might be a decent approach with the correct setup...

Comment: @zipzit : "why Knot" excellent pun.

Comment: @JeanMarie.  Thx.  But... as I get into it, my descriptive geometry model really depends on varying θ as the control parameter.  The BSpline/Nurb model uses a totally different type of parameter.  No good way to transfer the angle parameter to the Nurb method input parameter, sigh.  Knot good.

Comment: @zipzit A continuous function approximation $ x=a \cos^n t,\, y=b \sin ^n t $  where $n$ is a sufficiently large even integer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Piecewise vs Parametric**

As discussed in the comments this can be done piecewise or parametrically. The difference is minor. Any pieces of a piecewise function can be joined into a single function by the following:

$$f(t)=\begin{cases} f_1(t) & a_0<t\le a_1 \\ f_2(t) & a_1 < t \le a_2 \\ f_3(t) & a_2<t\le a_3 \\ & etc\end{cases}$$

$$f(t)=p[a_0,a_1,t]f_1(t)+p[a_1,a_2,t]f_2(t)+p[a_2,a_3,t]f_3(t)+\cdots$$

where $p[n,m,x]=\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\frac{|x-n|}{x-n}\cdot\frac{|x-m|}{x-m}\right)$. The function $p$ returns $1$ when $n<x<m$ and $0$ otherwise.

**Piecewise Solution**

$a$ is the horizontal "radius" of the pipe. I.e. the horizontal distance between the two sides is $2a$.

$b$ is the vertical "radius" of the pipe. I.e. the vertical distance between the two sides is $2b$.

$r$ is the radius of the corner pieces.

$$f(t)=\begin{cases}
 \{a,-(b-r)(2t-1)\} & 0\le t\le 1 \\
 \left\{a-r+r \cos \left(\frac{1}{2} \pi  (t-1)\right),-b+r-r \sin
   \left(\frac{1}{2} \pi  (t-1)\right)\right\} & 1<t\le 2 \\
 \{-(a-r) (2t-5),-b\} & 2<t\le 3 \\
 \left\{-a+r-r \sin \left(\frac{1}{2} \pi  (t-3)\right),-b+r-r \cos
   \left(\frac{1}{2} \pi  (t-3)\right)\right\} & 3<t\le 4 \\
 \{-a,(b-r) (2t-9)\} & 4<t\le 5 \\
 \left\{-a+r-r \cos \left(\frac{1}{2} \pi  (t-5)\right),b-r+r \sin
   \left(\frac{1}{2} \pi  (t-5)\right)\right\} & 5<t\le 6 \\
 \{(a-r) (2t-13),b\} & 6<t\le 7 \\
 \left\{a-r+r \sin \left(\frac{1}{2} \pi  (t-7)\right),b-r+r \cos
   \left(\frac{1}{2} \pi  (t-7)\right)\right\} & 7<t\le 8
\end{cases}$$

This varies the parameter $t$ over the range $[0,8]$. If a range of $[0,2\pi]$ is required then just apply a scaling factor: $g(t)=f\left(\frac{4t}{\pi}\right)$

**Image $(a=1,b=1,r=0.5)$**

[image]

**Image $(a=8,b=5,r=2)$**

[image]

Comment: Ian, At first glance, pretty awesome work.  I'm going to need a day to digest this, before accepting if that's okay?   Is that a Matlab --> gif image?  That `-2rt` characteristic blows me away with its simplicity.

Comment: The graphic is done in Mathematica. I can add extra images (with different parameters if you like them).

Comment: Your mention of the $2rt$ term highlighted a mistake in my method due to use $r=a/2=b/2$ in my test image. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I think for 4 < t < 5 the line should read { −, (−)(2−9) }

Comment: @aferriss Thanks. fixed.