# Parameterization of a parallelogram in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: parametrization

I have a parallelogram in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the vertices $(0,0,0),(1,1,-1), (1,1,1), (2,2,0)$. How would I find the parameterization of this?
Thanks!

Comment: What have you done?

Comment: I don't quite understand how parameterization works, so I have nothing so far

Comment: So, I guess you should read first what a parametrization is and look at some examples.

Comment: Think of it as finding a system of coordinates for points in the parallelogram. Try it in two dimensions first to get some ideas.

Comment: Here is the parametrization of [rectangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69099/equation-of-a-rectangle/279209#279209), this might help.

Comment: @amsmath It seems OP already knows the definition of parametrization and some examples. Actually, it is is not straightforward to parametrize parallelogram. See the example of rectangle above.

Comment: @ersh What you refer to is a parametrization of the boundary. I am sure OP wants a parametrization of the whole figure.

Comment: I understand the main idea of parameterization and why it is useful. I have never seen how to parameterize a non-smooth object and I can't find any good examples that explain how to do this in the 3rd dimension

Comment: Trying a different tack, can you find a parameterization of the unit square in $\mathbb R^2$? Having done that, can you think of a simple way to map the unit square onto a parallelogram?