# Explain Triangle perimeter in polar coordinates

Tags: geometry, ordinary-differential-equations, polar-coordinates, parametric

*The question is to give a formula in $x$ and $y$ that gives all three sides of an equilateral triangle.  The formula should not be true for points that are not part of the perimeter of the triangle. By this sub-problem, I am trying to understand deeper the page 809 and attack problem 11 on page 813 [here](https://noppa.aalto.fi/noppa/kurssi/mat-1.1020/materiaali/Mat-1_1020_juhani_pitkaranta__tkk_n_laaja_matematiikka_ii__2007_.pdf?state:CourseAdditionalMaterial=BrO0ABXcgAAAAAgAAGWVkaXRVc2VyV2FudHNUb0NoYW5nZUZpbGVzcgARamF2YS5sYW5nLkJvb2xlYW7NIHKA1Zz67gIAAVoABXZhbHVleHAAdxMAABBlZGl0RGlhbG9nSGlkZGVuc3EAfgAAAQ%3D%3D) -- there the purpose of parametrization is to find solutions to the partial differentials $\triangle u=0$, so-called boundary-problem and Dirichet's condition.*

**Trial 0**

J.M. hinted the parametrization [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/41954/5902),  through $(1,0)$?

$$\displaystyle r=\frac{\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)}{\cos\left(\left(\theta \mod \frac{2\pi}{n}\right) -\frac{\pi}{n}\right)} \;$$

[image]

I cannot understand the order of the division yet. I can understand the radius part but not why a line in the triangle, it must be due to some identity. Look I could do this with a small change (reciprocal of the radius):

```
n=3;
theta=(0:999)/1000;
r=cos(2*pi*(n*theta)%%1/n-pi/n)/cos(pi/n);
plot(r*cos(2*pi*theta),r*sin(2*pi*theta),asp=1,xlab="X",ylab="Y",
        main=paste("Regular ",n,"-gon",sep=""),type='l');
```

[image]

```
n=3;
theta=(0:999)/1000;
#r=cos(pi/n)/cos(2*pi*(n*theta)%%1/n-pi/n);
r=cos(2*pi*(n*theta)%%1/n-pi/n)/cos(pi/n);
plot(r*cos(2*pi*theta),r*sin(2*pi*theta),asp=1,xlab="X",ylab="Y",
        main=paste("Regular ",n,"-gon",sep=""),type='l');
r=cos(pi/n)/cos(2*pi*(n*theta)%%1/n-pi/n);
lines(r*cos(2*pi*theta),r*sin(2*pi*theta),asp=1,xlab="X",ylab="Y",
        main=paste("Regular ",n,"-gon",sep=""),type='l');
```

[image]

**Trial 1**

David Wallace instructed me [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3931719#3931719) to use polar coordinates and the floor function to describe the perimeter of the triangle apparently so that

$$\begin{cases}x=r\cos(\theta)\\y=r\sin(\theta)\end{cases}$$

$$r\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}\left(\frac{3\theta}{2\pi}-\left\lfloor\frac{3\theta}{2\pi}\right\rfloor\right) -\frac{\pi}{3}\right) = 1$$

...cannot understand this at all, hard to see the parametric form here.

**Perhaps related**

1. Something about plotting the function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9837766)
2. [Is there an equation to describe regular polygons?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41940/is-there-an-equation-to-describe-regular-polygons/41954#41954)

Comment: OK, in polar co-ordinates, I think it's something like $$r\cos(\frac{2\pi}{3}(\frac{3\theta}{2\pi}-\lfloor\frac{3\theta}{2\pi}\rfloor) -\frac{\pi}{3}) = 1 $$. Still need to convert it back to rectangular co-ordinates.

Comment: @David and hhh: Raskolnikov gave a derivation of the general case of a regular polygon [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/41954), which is easily adaptable to the case of an equilateral triangle.

Comment: What exactly isn't clear in Raskolnikov's answer?

Comment: That was explained in Raskolnikov's answer. Again: **have you read it**?