# Polygon sine waves

Tags: geometry, functions, trigonometry, polygons

So I came across [this picture](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/1bOQNmazpHzWHNlfuVRk14VgUieJRZSxRP3_VBQo0VT-=w500-h450-no) on Google+ and I wanted to understand further. I created an equation for the second wave, the one with the square. Here it is:
$$y=\frac{\sin x}{\cos(\min(x \mod \pi/2, \pi/2- (x \mod \pi/2)))}$$

(The equation plotted on [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%28x%29%2Fcos%28min%28%28x%29mod%28pi%2F2%29%2C+pi%2F2-+%28%28x%29mod%28pi%2F2%29%29%29%29).)

It's fine, but I feel like using mod and min is kind of nasty. Can anyone offer improvement to my equation and/or general insight towards further polygons?

Comment: Are there discontinuities in the plots? Do you really want those?

Comment: Yes, there are. I don't want them, but I wanted to make the equation as simple as possible

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41940) is a related question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with a "triangle" function of period $2 \pi/n$, minimum value $0$ and maximum value $\pi/n$: a suitable choice is $T_n(t) = \frac{1}{n} \arccos(\cos(n t))$.  A regular $n$-gon of inradius $r_0$ is given, in polar coordinates, by $r = r_0/\cos(T_n(\theta - \theta_0))$.  Its $y$ coordinate is then
$$y = \dfrac{r_0 \sin(\theta)}{\cos(T_n(\theta - \theta_0))}$$

Here is a similar animation using a pentagon ($n=5$):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm not sure I understand. How do you find the T function? The one you provided simplifies itself to the argument for any n. Can you please explain further? Cool animation btw

Comment: No, it's not the argument.  The point is that by definition $\arccos(anything)$ is always in the interval $[0, \pi]$.  For $0 \le t \le \pi/n$ you do have $T_n(t) = t$.  But in the next interval $\pi/n \le t \le 2\pi/n$ you get $T_n(t) = 2\pi/n - t$ (its value at $t = \pi/n$ is $\pi/n$, but at $t = 2\pi/n$ it's back to $0$).  And then it repeats.  The result is a "triangular wave".