# Polar equation for a Heptagon

Tags: geometry, polar-coordinates

What is polar equation of a Heptagon ?
I need to move some Android views in the form of a heptagon, for I need to have polar equations for Heptagon like for $x= r\sin(\theta)$ and $y=r\cos(\theta)$.

Is it possible to have polar equation for a heptagon too ?

Comment: You solution lies [here](http://mindblownmath.wordpress.com/2014/02/02/polar-equation-of-a-hexagon/)

Comment: Its 6 sided, it would be great i could get it for 7 or 8 sided polygon !

Comment: then have a look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/41946/148211)

Comment: ^ but not at that (accepted) answer, but rather the one below it, which gives a polar equation for general $n$.

Answer (score 1):

A general formula for a regular polygon of radius $r$ with $n$ sides, denote $c_n = \cos(\pi/n)$, $s_n = \sin(\pi/n)$ and

$$f_n(x+iy) = \left||rs_n - |y|| - (rs_n - |y|)\right| + |x-rc_n|$$

then your polygon is given by

$$\prod_{k = 0}^{n-1} f_n\left(e^{-\frac{2 i k \pi}{n}} (x+iy)\right) = 0$$

(For heptagone $n = 7$).

Comment: I need polar equations :( in terms of Theta