# Tracing the sides of an equilateral triangle

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, triangles

Is there any way I can get the points in 2D plane on the sides of an **equilateral** triangle for certain infinite animation sequence?

For example in case of tracing the circumference of the circle, I have the polar coordinates for $x$ and $y$ as
$$x=radius\times cosine(\theta)$$
$$y=radius\times sine(\theta)$$

I'm unable to figure how to take care of the discontinuity at the 3 vertexes

Comment: Can you plot 3 separate line segments or do you require a path which follows all three edges of the triangle?  And what are the co-ordinates of the bottom left corner?

Comment: @RobertFrost I've drawn 3 separate lines each have coordinates - **x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3**

Answer (score 4):

I found this answer to be useful: [Is there an equation to describe regular polygons?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41940/is-there-an-equation-to-describe-regular-polygons)

You can use absolute values or modular arithmetic to take care of the discontinuities. Here's one possible formula, which will trace out an equilateral triangle centered on the origin:

Let $k \equiv \frac{2\pi}{3}$. (In general, we divide $2\pi$ by the number of sides of the polygon we want to draw).

$$\begin{align*}
r(\theta) = \frac{\cos{\left(\frac{k}{2}\right)}}{\cos{\left(-\frac{k}{2} + \;\theta \,\text{mod}\; k\right)}}
\end{align*}$$

And you can plot this for every value of $\theta$ between 0 and $2\pi$.

If you want a larger triangle, multiply $r(\theta)$ by a suitable number. And if you want to rotate the triangle, replace $\theta$ with $\theta+d$ 
for some rotation amount $d$.

Finally, if you want to have a formula in rectangular coordinates, you can use the polar-to-rectangular transformation:

$$\begin{align*}x(\theta) &= r(\theta)\times \cos{\theta}\\y(\theta)&=r(\theta)\times \sin{\theta} .\end{align*}$$

I hope that helps!