# Are there equations for general shapes (not necessarily regular)?

Tags: geometry, graphing-functions

I was playing around on DESMOS and I discovered an equation for a triangle. So I got curious and was wondering if there are equations for other shapes (not necessarily regular) ? For example, a circle has the equation $x^2+y^2=a$, a square has the equation $\lim_{n \to \infty} x^n+y^n=a$ or an irregular triangle (which I discovered) has the equation $\lim_{n\to \infty}x^n+y^n=x+y$? And by extension is there any way to create the same shapes but then regular?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have suppressed tag "graph-theory" which deals with completely different "mathematical beings"...

Comment: Do you mean equations for having polygons with rounded corners ?

Comment: You can [make regular stars](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41940/is-there-an-equation-to-describe-regular-polygons?rq=1). Maybe transforming part of the equation in the link will give you irregular shapes

Comment: Somewhat, although I'm not sure how to describe it cause for example, the equation of square 'approaches a perfect square' as $n$ goes to infinity

Comment: I have to wonder if [this is relevant](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A0L_PZwuGHY), given the proximity in time.

Comment: Ultimately this may lead to [Fourier series drawing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r6sGWTCMz2k) (YouTube video), though I'm not sure if that's beyond what you intended.

Comment: The “If you are willing to use limits” answer is not visible to me/others, but did appear in the inbox as I followed this question. Why?